# SQL Server 2008 Database Engine doesn't connect

Tags: sql-server-2008

I just installed SQL Server Management Studio 10.0 (2008).

When I first opened it, I got this database engine screen, with no name under Server name tab.

Any name I've tried so far, never connects to any database (including (local)).

How should I proceed ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
<session-factory>
 <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
<property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect</property>
<property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
<property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=NHSchema.sdf</property>

<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="format_sql">true</property>
</session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Thanks

Comment: Management Studio is just the client. Unless you've installed or have available to you a server component, then it's not much use by itself.

Answer (score 0):

First configure the database engine protocols. 
e.g. to connect remotely enable TCP/IP

Then in the connection specify the `servername` or `server\instancename` if it is not the default instance.

You will also need permissions on the database to connect. If you are an administrator you should already have permissions.

Comment: Actually, I just connected to it. Now, I'm trying to create a DB through NHibernate, but it says I can't connect to the DB or I don't have permission. My config is in my first post ! Thanks ! In the above code, NHSchema.sdf is a database previously created on the management.